# наследование, первичный конструктор базового класса не имеет параметров

Tags: ооп, kotlin

В базовом классе в первичном конструкторе нет параметров, а в производном классе в первичном контрукторе параметры есть. Как правильно создать производный класс? Ошибка

```
//здесь ошибка, подчеркнута буква A
class B(c: Int) : A {
```

Полный код ниже

**Main.kt**

```
package ru.site

fun main() {

 //должен передать аргументы базового класса, затем свои
 var b: B = B(5, 10, 15)

 println(b.fsum())

}

//базовый класс
open class A {

 protected var a: Int
 private var b: Int

 constructor(a: Int, b: Int) {
  this.a = a
  this.b = b
 }

 fun fa(): Int {
  return this.a
 }

 fun fb(): Int {
  return this.b
 }

}

//производный класс
//здесь ошибка, подчеркнута буква A
class B(c: Int) : A {

 private var c: Int

 init {
  this.c = c
 }


 //производный классдолжен повторить параметры
 //базового класса, затем свои параметры
 //вызов конструктора базового класса через super
 constructor(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) : this(c) {

 }

 fun fsum(): Int {
  return this.c + a
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если навести курсор на подчеркнутый код, то вы увидите описание ошибки:

[image: Скриншот]

Фактически в первичном конструкторе класса `B` вы не вызываете никакого конструктора родительского класса. Если в классе `A` явно прописать, что у вас есть публичный первичный конструктор, то будет другая ошибка: будет ругаться, что в этом классе не инициализируются поля `a` и `b` ("поля должны быть инициализированы или абстрактны").

Фактически ваш класс `A` не знает, чем должны быть инициализированы поля, когда вызван конструктор без параметров. Оставить их "пустыми" - нет, не прокатит.

Лучше делать наоборот: в первичном конструкторе определить конструктор с максимумом параметров, а потом определить вторичный конструктор без параметров, в нем вызвать первичный с указанием чему должны быть равны пропущенные параметры (от наиболее общего случая к частным случаям).

```
open class A(protected var a: Int, private var b: Int) {

    constructor(): this(1, 2)  // Вызываем первичный конструктор

    fun fa(): Int {
        return a  // this не обязательно
    }

    fun fb(): Int {
        return b  // this не обязательно
    }
}


class B(a: Int, b: Int, private var c: Int) : A(a, b) {

    constructor(): this(1,2,3)  // Вызываем первичный конструктор

    fun fsum(): Int {
        return c + a // this не обязательно
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/owI_qsqJR)

Comment: Здравствуте insolor! Спасибо Вам! Вы совершенно правы. Я исследовал 4 варианта, 3 вариант не работает, как ни крути. Список вариантов. 
1) базовый первичный конструктор есть — производный первичный конструктор есть 
2) базовый первичный конструктор есть — производный первичный конструктор нет 
3) базовый первичный конструктор нет — производный первичный конструктор есть 
4) базовый первичный конструктор нет — производный первичный конструктор нет